How to use chrome API in existing next app
I am creating a bookmarking app using next.js. I want to setup a button on clicking which, the bookmarks open up in a tab group in the browser. But for that, I need to be able to use the chrome API in my next.js app. Is there any way I can use chrome api inside next.js?

No, you'll need to make a companion extension.

@woxxom If I create an extension, will it be possible to implement the above functionality inside the webapp only?

No, the app will send a message to the extension, which will call the API with the data from the message.
